# How to install meteor on FreeBSD?

Tags: build, installation, meteor, freebsd

I'm trying to run meteorjs on FreeBSD 9.
I already have nodejs installed from ports.

I also tried:
`git clone https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git` and then `node meteor --help` but it does not work.

And I found this "if" into meteor file:

```
if [ "$UNAME" != "Linux" -a "$UNAME" != "Darwin" ] ; then
    echo "Sorry, this OS is not supported."
    exit 1
fi
```

Is there some info on how to install or build meteorjs on FreeBSD?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just removing the exit 1?

Answer (score 7):

I've created a custom dev bundle for FreeBSD: https://github.com/yonas/meteor-freebsd

Here are the installation instructions:

### Install required packages

```
sudo pkg install bash ca_root_nss curl expat gettext-runtime git-lite gmake indexinfo libevent2 libffi mongodb node npm pcre perl5 python2 python27 snappy v8
```

### Install Meteor

```
git clone git://github.com/yonas/meteor-freebsd.git
sudo mv meteor-freebsd /usr/local/share/meteor
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/meteor/meteor /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

### Create and launch an app

```
meteor create myapp
cd myapp
meteor
```

Answer (score 3):

Meteor does not officially support FreeBSD, but it might work. You'll need to generate your own 'dev bundle' (per https://github.com/meteor/meteor#slow-start-for-developers).

First, you'll need to disable the OS specific safety belts in `meteor` and `admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh`. You'll also need to get MongoDB binaries from somewhere, as 10gen does not provide pre-built binaries for FreeBSD.

In theory, you should then be able to build a dev bundle with the script. The dev bundle should be the only OS specific portion of meteor, once you have a working dev bundle the rest of the code should run normally.

Comment: FYI, mongodb is available in the databases/mongodb port.